# Why am I getting the message Keyword error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've been trying to read an xls file in python, but when I try to select the first column of any table I get the message `KeyError: 'NOME'`.

I've tried `list(df.columns.values)` to see if NOME is among the table columns and the message was `['NOME ', 'SOBRENOME', 'IDADE', 'SEXO', 'PROFISSAO']`, which I suppose proves my column is there.

This is what I get when I ask to print df, which is the var I'm using in this case.

```
        NOME     SOBRENOME  IDADE   SEXO    PROFISSAO
    0   Giraldo  Freire     25      M       Escritor
    1   Paulo    Moraes     35      M       Bombeiro
    2   Susanne  Silva      42      F       Domestica
    3   Carine   Teobaldo   33      F       Secretaria
```

I've also tried this code:

```py
colstokeep = ['NOME ', 'SOBRENOME', 'IDADE', 'SEXO', 'PROFISSAO']
df = df[colstokeep]
df = df.set_index(['NOME'])
```

But the message I get is:

`KeyError: "None of ['NOME'] are in the columns"`

Could you please help me?

Comment: Your column name contains a space. `NOME ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this @Psidom was just perfect

```
colstokeep = ['NOME', 'SOBRENOME', 'IDADE', 'SEXO', 'PROFISSAO'] 
df = df[colstokeep] 
df = df.set_index('NOME')
```